# Python Convert json.loads() to Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have something like:

```
sysbus = json.loads(file)

print sysbus
>>> [{u'eth3': u'pci@0000:03:00.1', u'eth2': u'pci@0000:03:00.0', u'eth1': u'pci@0000:06:00.1', u'eth0': u'pci@0000:06:00.0'}]
```

I would like to convert sysbus into a dictionary.

```
{'eth3': 'pci@0000:03:00.1', 'eth2': 'pci@0000:03:00.0', 'eth1': 'pci@0000:06:00.1', 'eth0': 'pci@0000:06:00.0'}
```

What is the cleanest way to convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want the first item from this list, so get that:

```
sysbus = json.loads(file)[0]
```

Do you expect this `file` could somehow contain multiple entries in the list? If yes, then you might want to check the length for the list first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Anyway to modify sysbus? i.e. convert from a list to a dictionary and drop unicode characters?

Comment: @user3330722 — there are no unicode characters here. Just unicode strings. Do you have a specific reason to want to convert them to bytestrings?

Comment: Yes, I would like to convert them so it looks exactly like the dictionary in the question. The end goal is to compare it to the same dictionary so it must match.

Comment: @user3330722 No, it doesn't, `{'a': 1} == {u'a': 1}` is `True` if you're using Python 2. If you're using Python 3, then the dictionary you're comparing to should probably be unicode in the first place.